How to set iTerm2 color to darkmode with powerlevel10k
I'm setting up iTerm2 on a new macbook using brew and cannot figure out how to get darkmode set.
I ran brew install iTerm2 and then brew install zsh, and then installed ohmyzsh using.
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

I then installed powerlevel10k and updated my zshrc.
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k

Everything seems to be working fine but my terminal background is still light. If I try to change the colors in iTerm settings -> profiles -> colors -> darkMode, I get a notice saying "Your current theme overrides the system light and dark mode setting, so color switching will not occur. You can change it in Settings > Appearance > General > Theme". Change in Settings > Appearance > General > Theme only changes the top bar.
So: how do I get dark mode and keep powerlevel10k?
My current .zshrc for reference
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

source /opt/homebrew/share/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-history-substring-search/zsh-history-substring-search.zsh

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"


# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh


# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.

plugins=(git alias-finder zsh-autosuggestions zsh-history-substring-search)


iTerm2 Preferences -> Profiles -> Click on your profile -> Colors -> Basic Colors -> Background

This is not a solution for me. As I noted in the post, if I change the color there, I get a notice. "Your current theme overrides the system light and dark mode setting, so color switching will not occur." This makes me think something else in oh-my-zsh or powerlevel10k is overriding the color setting.

If you only want to use Dark mode, you might want to try this step.
I tried and it works.

Open Iterm2
Iterm2 -> Settings -> Appearance -> General
Set "Theme" = Dark

Iterm2 -> Profiles -> select your profile or default
Select "Colors" tab
Turn on the checkbox "use different colors for light mode and dark mode"

(Note: If it is already ON, then switch Off and ON again)
Switch "Editing" to "Dark mode"
Turn off the checkbox at step 6.


DONE.


Ha! Excellent!
It worked for me. What a bizarre solution. I have no idea how you found it.
Thanks!

Master! Needed this in 2024

Somehow it roll back to light mode after close the settings tab

This worked for me previously, now it doesn't anymore (probably a newer version of iterm2)

What a bizzare way to change the colors. It should be a simple toggle.

Does not work any more on 3.5.10. Do we need to waste so much time for just finding a way to hack the theme setting!?

I found this answer to be correct: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/476522/how-to-switch-to-a-dark-background-in-iterm2
Basically, in Profiles >> Colors, click the "Color Presets" dropdown and select "Dark Background". This did what I wanted, which appears to also be what you want.

